# How to create a cq5 page programatically from external environment?

Tags: content-management-system, aem

We planned to create a CQ5 website from other cms, as per the requirements it has appx 1000 pages.It will take huge to time to create a page and author the content manually.So we decided to write utility for each template to create a page and author content.

It can be possible to write a utility inside CQ5 by using WCM API. But I want this to done from external environment i.e., outside CQ5. I have wrote the code but I couldn't get the ResourceResolver object in my java main its showing null pointer exception.

Please suggest me a way to achieve this It would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I am looking to create a pages with respective components placed in the parysys with content.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create new pages via a POST to the CQ instance, as long as the authenticated user has the required rights. [Manipulating content](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html) illustrates what can be done.

Here is a small example.

```
curl -u admin:admin \
 -F"jcr:primaryType=cq:Page" \
 http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/index

curl -u admin:admin \
 -F"jcr:primaryType=cq:PageContent" \
 -F"sling:resourceType=geometrixx/components/homepage" \
 -F"jcr:title=My new Homepage" \
 http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/index/jcr:content
```

creates a new page and its jcr:content node. Creating components works that way as well.

A different approach would be, creating the required content structure in XML and import it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0"         
    xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" 
    xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Page">
  <jcr:content
      cq:lastModified="{Date}2015-03-09T21:05:46.442Z"
      cq:lastModifiedBy="admin"
      jcr:primaryType="cq:PageContent"
      jcr:title="My new Homepage"
      sling:resourceType="geometrixx/components/homepage"/>
</jcr:root>
```

Using the [simple-content-package-archetype](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/core/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool/vlt-mavenplugin.html#simple-content-package-archetype) you could create content programmatically and deploy it on the server easily.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I am looking to create a pages with respective components placed in the parysys with content.

Comment: Thank you.But I think it won't work for creating the page the template path is mandatory. And how the multiple parsys will be created with layouts

Comment: When you know the template path you just set is as a property and of course you have to know how a page with template /x/y/z is structured. But when you have the information needed, there is no reason why it shouldn't work. In previous projects we did a lot of content migrations that way and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Through curl itself shall I place the components in parsys.

Comment: No, you miss my point. Content creation can be done via cURL, XML imports, JSON imports etc. The only aspect you have to think of is the correct structure. The rest is text, which you have to create. The XML for example may also contain a parsys node which contains an Image component.

Comment: Suppose I have custom component which has two properties title and description. When I place this component manually in any page and author the content thru dialog and its get reflected in JCR based on components and its properties .If the samething have to be automated how it will be done ?\

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to first get access to the JCR repository. [Link here](https://cqwemblog.wordpress.com/2013/12/29/ways-to-access-jcr-repository-in-cq5/)

By making an Authenticated Request you can then save the data to CQ. I would suggest using JCROM or sling models to create your DAO and models and then do a post request to save the data in JCR. You can use workflows as well in the process to save the data.